# Is it possible to define GTK+ type using gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtk, glib, gtkmm

I would like to define a new subclass of some gtkmm type, implementing interface of underlying GTK+ object. Then, i want to compile it into some kind of dll and use in pure C code (GTK+, no gtkmm) through this interface. Is it possible?

Comment: The result will necessarily be a C++ class. There's no way to use a C++ class from C, but you can of course write a C wrapper around it. Would be a bit roundabout though, wouldn't it? If you want to use it in C, why not just write it in C?

Comment: Because GTK+-style inheritance results in bloated code. Moreover I want to use C++ objects in newly defined class.

Comment: Technically it could be possible without writting any additional wrapper - we'd just need to tell to the GTK+ magic layer how big the object is and tell somewhat how to call the constructor. The question is - how to do it in non-hacky way (if such exists).

Comment: "Because GTK+-style inheritance results in bloated code." Inheritance is inherently complicated. All that 'bloat' is going on in C++ too, only under the hood.

Comment: Of course, but the code remains clearer. Overhead is not a problem in my case.

Comment: An intermediate solution might be Vala instead of C++. You would get the best of both.

Answer (score 0):

The followings are required to use *gtkmm* widget in *GTK+*:

1. implement the desired custom widget in *gtkmm*
2. create a library from the widget for *Glade*
3. design the user interface containing the custom widget with *Glade*
4. declare the *C* interface for the application written in *GTK+*
5. build the user interface from XML with `GtkBuilder`

Details can be found in my [blog post](http://szilard.blogs.balabit.com/en/2013/02/how-to-use-gtkmm-custom-widget-in-gtk/).