# How do I add a custom gtkmm widget to glade?

Tags: gtk, widget, glade, gtkmm

I'm writing a [custom widget using gtkmm](https://github.com/bstpierre/gtk-date-chooser), and I haven't been able to get it to work in glade. (The widget itself is barely functional; it does work, and I want to get it to work in glade before moving on to the next step.) Glade finds the widget, but when I try to place it in a window, glade crashes.

Based on hints I found during various searches, I added this bit of code to the main source file:

```
extern "C"
{
    GType date_chooser_get_type(void)
    {
        return DateChooser::get_type();
    }
}
```

I have a suspicion that the code above isn't right, but I can't find any gtkmm or glade documentation about what this function should do.

Based on the [catalog documentation for glade](http://developer.gnome.org/gladeui/stable/catalogintro.html), I created the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<glade-catalog name="gtk-date-chooser" library="libgtkdatechooser-0.1.so" language="c++">
  <glade-widget-classes>
    <glade-widget-class name="DateChooser" generic-name="date-chooser" title="Date Chooser" />
  </glade-widget-classes>
  <glade-widget-group name="date" title="Date">
    <glade-widget-class-ref name="DateChooser"/>
  </glade-widget-group>
</glade-catalog>
```

This is in the root of my widget's source directory with the name `gtk-date-chooser.xml`. I run glade in that directory using:

```
GLADE_CATALOG_SEARCH_PATH=. GLADE_MODULE_SEARCH_PATH=./.libs glade
```

When the window comes up, my widget appears in a special "Date" group as specified in the catalog, with a default icon. If I place a window and then select the widget for placement in the window, glade crashes. I see the following on the console:

```
GladeUI-Message: 2 missing displayable value for GtkWidget::events
GladeUI-Message: No displayable values for property GtkTreeSelection::mode
GladeUI-Message: 1 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererAccel::accel-mode
GladeUI-Message: 14 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererAccel::accel-mods

(glade:23757): GladeUI-CRITICAL **: gwa_list_signals: assertion `real_type != 0' failed

(glade:23757): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type `<invalid>'

(glade:23757): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_class_list_properties: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT_CLASS (class)' failed

(glade:23757): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type `<invalid>'

(glade:23757): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_class_list_child_properties: assertion `GTK_IS_CONTAINER_CLASS (cclass)' failed
GladeUI-Message: Glade needs artwork; a default icon will be used for the following classes:
    DateChooser needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-date-chooser-date-chooser'
**
GladeUI:ERROR:glade-signal-model.c:800:glade_signal_model_iter_n_children: code should not be reached
```

It seems like the answer to [this (unanswered) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727979/is-it-possible-to-define-gtk-type-using-gtkmm) might provide a clue, but I haven't been able to find any answer for that question or clues that will help with my problem.

Versions I'm using:

- Ubuntu: 12.04
- gtkmm: 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
- glade: 3.12.0-0ubuntu1

(I'd be willing to test solutions based on trunk versions, or on Centos 6 or Fedora 16.)

Comment: Is your custom widget a Gtk::DrawingArea (or could be implemented as that)?

Comment: I have the same problem.  It seems to be happening because the new type is not being properly registered.  This in turn depends on calling `Gtk::Main::init_gtkmm_internals()` in a library initialisation function, and doing so prevents glade from starting up properly.  Haven't figured out why yet, though.

Comment: @h3nr1x: No. Take a peek at the code linked above -- it's very simple.

Comment: There is also a longish discussion of this topic at https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2006-November/msg00132.html but it never comes to a conclusion of how to include Gtk-- widgets in a catalog.  The best I've managed is to leave an empty container and add the widget programmatically.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for the pointer. I don't know why I hadn't stumbled across that thread in my searches. Have you followed Oliver Nittka's example in [this message](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2006-November/msg00182.html)? I'm going to test it out tonight.

Comment: I've found this one of the most frustrating problems I've come across to try to hunt down, because the documentation seems to have been reorganised and move to a different server three or four times in the past couple of years.  So almost every article you find on the subject says, "read the documentation," complete with a dead link.

Comment: I've tried the example you linked - it doesn't work, at least not using the Ubuntu 12.04 versions of the libraries.  The call to init_gtkmm_internals never returns.

Comment: I second your comment about the documentation. I finally had a chance to compile the example linked above, and it seems to work for me on Ubuntu 12.04 after I tweaked the Makefile to use `-fPIC` in `CXXFLAGS` and `-L. -lsimpledraw` at the end of the link lines instead of explicitly naming libsimpledraw.so near the beginning. (And then running with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./simpledraw_ctortest`.)

Comment: Doh! I wrote that too soon -- the examples compile and run fine, but glade does not work at all.

Comment: @Tom: Your link to the thread above has been the most helpful thing I've found. If you post it as an answer with a bit of commentary, the +200 is yours unless someone swoops in with a solution...

Comment: I'm writing a blog post about the topic, I hope it can help solve your problem. I'll be back with it as an answer.

Comment: @Tom: See Szilárd Pfeiffer's answer -- it fixes the type registration piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I had a look but haven't had a chance to try it yet.  I couldn't see what was different to what we'd already tried.

Comment: I tried it and it works. Haven't done a close comparison yet, but there's some detail in the type creation that I wasn't doing right, and the example linked above was doing either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The followings are required to add a custom *gtkmm* widget to *Glade*:

1. at least one pure custom widget implementation
2. some *Glade*-related extra functions to the custom widgets
3. a catalog file which describes the custom widgets to Glade
4. a library contains the custom widgets and some Glade-related
   functions

The most important thing is the fact that *Glade* is written in *C* not in *C++*, so we have to be able to wrap a plan *C* widget to a *C++* one and we have to register this wrap function to the `GType` related to the custom widget. It looks something like the followings:

```
#include "custom_widget.h"

GType CustomWidget::gtype = 0;

CustomWidget::CustomWidget (GtkEntry *gobj) :
  Gtk::Entry (gobj)
{
}

CustomWidget::CustomWidget () :
  Glib::ObjectBase ("customwidget")
{
}

Glib::ObjectBase *
CustomWidget::wrap_new (GObject *o)
{
  if (gtk_widget_is_toplevel (GTK_WIDGET (o)))
    {
      return new CustomWidget (GTK_ENTRY (o));
    }
  else
    {
      return Gtk::manage(new CustomWidget (GTK_ENTRY (o)));
    }
}

void
CustomWidget::register_type ()
{
  if (gtype)
    return;

  CustomWidget dummy;

  GtkWidget *widget = GTK_WIDGET (dummy.gobj ());

  gtype = G_OBJECT_TYPE (widget);

  Glib::wrap_register (gtype, CustomWidget::wrap_new);
}
```

You should write the catalog file very carefully. Names must be correct (especially `glade-widget-class`) for the proper work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<glade-catalog name="customwidgets" library="customwidgetsglade" depends="gtk+">

  <init-function>custom_widgets_glade_init</init-function>

  <glade-widget-classes>
    <glade-widget-class name="gtkmm__CustomObject_customwidget" generic-name="customwidget" icon-name="widget-gtk-entry" title="Custom Widget">
    </glade-widget-class>
  </glade-widget-classes>

  <glade-widget-group name="customwidgets" title="Custom Widgets" >
    <glade-widget-class-ref name="gtkmm__CustomObject_customwidget" />
  </glade-widget-group>

</glade-catalog>
```

There is nothing to do, but implement the function, which registers our widget as the part of the initialization of our *Glade* library.

```
extern "C" void
custom_widgets_glade_init ()
{
  Gtk::Main::init_gtkmm_internals ();
  custom_widgets_register ();
}
```

Initializing *gtkmm* internals is a must, because  `custom_widgets_glade_init` is called from *Glade,* which is written in *C* not in *C++* so it initializes only the *GTK+*.

If you are interested in the topic you can find my blog post [here](http://szilard.blogs.balabit.com/en/2012/06/how-to-add-custom-gtkmm-widget-to-glade/) with more the details.

Comment: Sigh.  After a *long* time beating my head against this, realised that the example given only works with gtk-- 3.0, not with 2.4.

Comment: As far as I know it works with _gtkmm_ 2.x. I completed [my blog post](http://szilard.blogs.balabit.com/en/2012/06/how-to-add-custom-gtkmm-widget-to-glade/) with the appropriate commands (code compilation, _Glade_ related environment variables) and notes.

Comment: @SzilárdPfeiffer, do you still have the link? The one in your comment is broken...