# gtkmm: How do I use a custom widget in a GtkBuilder XML file?

Tags: c++, gtkmm4

I'm writing a gtkmm-4 application, and want to use a custom widget with `GtkBuilder` XML. If the widget is constructed from C++, it works fine. However, it doesn't render when constructed from XML.

**NOTE: This question might be considered a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826435/how-do-i-add-a-custom-gtkmm-widget-to-glade). I am not asking about using Glade with my widget; my widget simply does not work with plain, hand-written XML.**

I'm sorry for posting this much code, but I believe this is about as minimal as I can get it.

### Custom widget code

- joystick.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef _TASDI2_JOYSTICK_HPP_
#define _TASDI2_JOYSTICK_HPP_
#include <gtkmm.h>

namespace tasdi2 {
  class Joystick : public Gtk::Widget {
  public:
    Joystick();
    virtual ~Joystick() {}

    virtual Gtk::SizeRequestMode get_request_mode_vfunc() const override {
      return Gtk::Widget::get_request_mode_vfunc();
    }

    virtual void measure_vfunc(
      Gtk::Orientation orientation, int for_size, int& minimum, int& natural,
      int& minimum_baseline, int& natural_baseline) const override;
    
    void on_map() override;
    void on_unmap() override;
    
    void snapshot_vfunc(const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Snapshot> &snapshot) override;
    
    
    
    Glib::PropertyProxy<int> property_xpos() {
      return prop_xpos.get_proxy();
    }
    Glib::PropertyProxy_ReadOnly<int> property_xpos() const {
      return prop_xpos.get_proxy();
    }
    Glib::PropertyProxy<int> property_ypos() {
      return prop_ypos.get_proxy();
    }
    Glib::PropertyProxy_ReadOnly<int> property_ypos() const {
      return prop_ypos.get_proxy();
    }
  private:
    Glib::Property<int> prop_xpos;
    Glib::Property<int> prop_ypos;
  };
}  // namespace tasdi2
#endif
```

- joystick.cpp

```cpp
#include "joystick.hpp"
#include <gdkmm.h>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <numbers>

namespace {
  inline void circle(
    const Glib::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cairo, double cx, double cy, double r) {
    cairo->arc(cx, cy, r, 0, 2 * std::numbers::pi);
  }

  inline void line(
    const Glib::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cairo, double x1, double y1, double x2,
    double y2) {
    cairo->move_to(x1, y1);
    cairo->line_to(x2, y2);
  }
}  // namespace

namespace tasdi2 {
  Joystick::Joystick() :
    Glib::ObjectBase("Tasdi2Joystick"),
    Gtk::Widget(),
    prop_xpos(*this, "xpos", 0),
    prop_ypos(*this, "ypos", 0) {
    set_hexpand();
    set_hexpand_set();
    set_vexpand();
    set_vexpand_set();
  }

  void Joystick::measure_vfunc(
    Gtk::Orientation orientation, int for_size, int& minimum, int& natural,
    int& minimum_baseline, int& natural_baseline) const {
    minimum          = 128;
    natural          = 160;
    minimum_baseline = -1;
    natural_baseline = -1;
    return;
  }

  void Joystick::on_map() { Gtk::Widget::on_map(); }
  void Joystick::on_unmap() { Gtk::Widget::on_unmap(); }

  void Joystick::snapshot_vfunc(const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Snapshot>& snapshot) {
    const auto space = get_allocation();
    const Gdk::Rectangle rect(0, 0, space.get_width(), space.get_height());
    std::cout << "Allocation area: " << space.get_x() << ", " << space.get_y() << ", " << space.get_width() << ", " << space.get_height() << "\n";

    auto cairo = snapshot->append_cairo(rect);

    const double w  = space.get_width();
    const double h  = space.get_height();
    const double cx = w / 2;
    const double cy = h / 2;
    // colors
    const Gdk::RGBA color_bg0("#7F7F7F");
    const Gdk::RGBA color_bg1("#FFFFFF");
    const Gdk::RGBA color_oln("#000000");
    const Gdk::RGBA color_cln("#0000FF");
    const Gdk::RGBA color_dot("#FF0000");

    cairo->rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
    Gdk::Cairo::set_source_rgba(cairo, color_bg0);
    cairo->fill();

    circle(cairo, cx, cy, cx);
    Gdk::Cairo::set_source_rgba(cairo, color_bg1);
    cairo->fill_preserve();

    line(cairo, cx, 0, cx, h);
    line(cairo, 0, cy, w, cy);
    Gdk::Cairo::set_source_rgba(cairo, color_oln);
    cairo->stroke();
  }
}  // namespace tasdi2
```

### MVE test code

- In XML

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "joystick.hpp"

static const std::string ui_data = R"(
<interface>
  <object class="GtkAspectFrame" id="root">
    <property name="margin-start">10</property>
    <property name="margin-end">10</property>
    <property name="margin-top">10</property>
    <property name="margin-bottom">10</property>
    
    <child>
      <object class="gtkmm__CustomObject_Tasdi2Joystick" />
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
)";

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window {
public:
  MainWindow() :
    builder(Gtk::Builder::create_from_string(ui_data)) {
    
    set_child(*builder->get_widget<Gtk::AspectFrame>("root"));
    set_size_request(256, 256);
  }
protected:
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create("io.github.jgcodes2020.testapp");
  app->signal_startup().connect([&]() {
    tasdi2::Joystick joystick;
  });
  return app->make_window_and_run<MainWindow>(argc, argv);
}
```

[image: Empty window, nothing visible]

- in C++

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "joystick.hpp"

static const std::string ui_data = R"(
<interface>
  <object class="GtkAspectFrame" id="root">
    <property name="margin-start">10</property>
    <property name="margin-end">10</property>
    <property name="margin-top">10</property>
    <property name="margin-bottom">10</property>
  </object>
</interface>
)";

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window {
public:
  MainWindow() :
    builder(Gtk::Builder::create_from_string(ui_data)) {
    
    auto& root = *builder->get_widget<Gtk::AspectFrame>("root");
    root.set_child(stick);
    
    set_child(root);
    set_size_request(256, 256);
  }
protected:
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;
  tasdi2::Joystick stick;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create("io.github.jgcodes2020.testapp");
  return app->make_window_and_run<MainWindow>(argc, argv);
}
```

[image: Widget showing with circle and crosshair]

Comment: Not that I've experience with GtkBuilder but in general... If GtkBuilder shall be able to create your custom widget you _must_ register somehow a mapping from the resp. XML tag (string) to a function to create your widget. This is described in the online doc.: [Using derived widgets](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-builder-using-derived-widgets.html.en).

Comment: Please, note the comment I found in the sample code of [Using derived widgets](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-builder-using-derived-widgets.html.en): _`// Create a dummy instance before the call to refBuilder->add_from_file().
  // This creation registers DerivedButton's class in the GType system.
  // This is necessary because DerivedButton contains user-defined properties
  // (Glib::Property) and is created by Gtk::Builder.`_ and the resp. call _`static_cast<void>(DerivedButton());`_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the comments above about including derived widgets, I reviewed the sample code out on the Gnome developer site and reviewed the class constructor for your "Joystick" widget.  I left your standard constructor alone as it would be useful for any widget directly built in your code.  Then, using the derived widget example on the developer site, I revised the "joystick.hpp" header file to include the builder constructor prototype as follows.

```
Joystick();
Joystick(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refGlade); /* New builder function for a derived widget */
virtual ~Joystick() {}
```

Then within the "tasdi2" namespace in file "joystick.cpp", I added the derived builder constructor function, basically cloning the detail within the standard constructor for the "Joystick" class.

```
Joystick::Joystick(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& /* refGlade */)
: // To register custom properties, you must register a custom GType.  If
  // you don't know what that means, don't worry, just remember to add
  // this Glib::ObjectBase constructor call to your class' constructor.
  // The GType name will be gtkmm__CustomObject_Tasdi2Joystick.
  Glib::ObjectBase("Tasdi2Joystick"),
  Gtk::Widget(cobject),
  prop_xpos(*this, "xpos", 0),
  prop_ypos(*this, "ypos", 0)
{
    set_hexpand();
    set_hexpand_set();
    set_vexpand();
    set_vexpand_set();
}
```

Finally, within the "XML" version of "main.cpp", I revised the code to accommodate the derived widget.  In your XML text body, I added an "ID" attribute so that calling the derived builder function later on in the program has a hook to the widget.

```
<object class="gtkmm__CustomObject_Tasdi2Joystick" id="stick_range"/>
```

Along with the addition of an "ID" attribute, I included the building of the custom joystick widget within the "MainWindow" constructor.

```
  MainWindow() :
    builder(Gtk::Builder::create_from_string(ui_data)) {
    set_child(*builder->get_widget<Gtk::AspectFrame>("root"));
    set_size_request(256, 256);
    tasdi2::Joystick * stick_range = nullptr;
    stick_range = Gtk::Builder::get_widget_derived<tasdi2::Joystick>(builder, "stick_range");
    if (stick_range == nullptr) 
       printf("Joystick widget definition was not found\n");
  }
```

The net result of combining your "XML" version of "main.cpp" with the additional changes displayed the widget.

[image: Sample Joystick]

You may already have figured this stuff out from the previous comments, but if not, these additional code snippets may be of use to you.

Regards.